# Null Pointer Exception caused by getPackageManager()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-messaging

So I'm trying to implement gcm or my app with the help of [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-register). However, when trying to launch my application, I get following error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
```

Here is the code in question:

```
private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
```

What is my mistake here?

EDIT: Where I'm using "getAppVersion":

```
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAGD, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
        // the new app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAGD, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
```

and

```
private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAGD, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Where I start getRegistrationId:
in the onCreate method,

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAGD, "No valid GPS APK found.");
        }
```

Comment: Please show where and how you are calling `getAppVersion()`.

Comment: Alright, edited my answer with the snippets of code containing getAppversion

Comment: That actually didn't help a lot. Where is `context` coming from? Either it is `null`, or it is not yet ready for use (e.g., you are calling it from a data member initializer of an activity or service).

Comment: ... and now show where you are calling `storeRegistrationId`. A null Context is getting passed at some point - I notice the docs are kind of incomplete - in their example they are passing a `context` but never show how it was obtained.

Comment: @CommonsWare Context is just defined in the class as `Context context;`. @trooper I am calling "storeRegistrationId" in "registerInBackground", just look up the documentation. I pretty much copied the code from there and am now trying to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: "Context is just defined in the class as Context context" -- and where are you assigning a value to it?

Comment: I have looked at the docs just_deko, and my comment was meant to point out the problem - the example doesn't show where context is initialized (and so following that example blindly you've also failed to initialize that variable). `Context context;` starts with a value of null. **You need to assign a value to it before you start passing it around.**